# How to load and save image in typed datagridview image column?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm recently Working with typed Datagridview for getting data from user like name, mobile no and user image. User can enter the name and mobile no, but how can I get the image in  Datagridview? and how to store the Datagridview image cell in Sql server 2008.

Here is my coding:

```
private void dataGridViewEx1_CellContentDoubleClick
            (object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog Dilg = new OpenFileDialog();
        DialogResult DRR = Dilg.ShowDialog();
        if (DRR == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex != -1)
            {
            dataGridViewEx1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[33].Value =       Image.FromFile(Dilg.FileName);
                dataGridViewEx1.Refresh();
                Application.DoEvents();                 
            }
            else
            {
                XtraMessageBox.Show("Out Of Range", "Information");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

But After using this code for loading image. The image load in Datagridview image cell but  other details like name and mobile no r erased from the same column .

How to  load the image without erasing other column data?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to have all data in one column? Why not just use separate columns for name, number and other. This way you won't need to worry about this.

DataGridView is not really meant to hold different types in one column.